# What is the difference between Quantum Physics, Quantum Theory, Quantum Mechanics, and Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, quantum-mechanics

What is the difference between Quantum Physics, [Quantum Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_theory), [Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), and [Quantum Field Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory)? Are they the same subject? I believe that they are not the same subject! Maybe there is not big difference between those subjects but I need to know what is main difference between those subjects and what is main intersection? Also I need to know which one is big subject relative to another?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3496/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Quantum mechanics (QM – also known as quantum physics, or quantum theory) is a branch of physics which deals with physical phenomena at microscopic scales, where the action is on the order of the Planck constant. Quantum mechanics departs from classical mechanics primarily at the quantum realm of atomic and subatomic length scales. Quantum mechanics provides a mathematical description of much of the dual particle-like and wave-like behavior and interactions of energy and matter. Quantum mechanics is the non-relativistic limit of Quantum Field Theory (QFT), a theory that was developed later that combined Quantum Mechanics with Relativity.
>
> Quantum field theory (QFT) is a theoretical framework for constructing quantum mechanical models of subatomic particles in particle physics and quasiparticles in condensed matter physics, by treating a particle as an excited state of an underlying physical field.

Some of the relativistic quantum field theories would be QED, QCD, and the Standard Model.

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Field_Theory

Comment: I strongly object to this answer. Quantum field theory is quantum mechanics when the mode spectrum is continuous. Relativity is absolutely not a prerequisite for quantum field theory. Condensed matter physics uses non-relativistic quantum field theory all the time as *even mentioned in the second paragraph of the answer*. Therefore, calling quantum mechanics the "non-relativistic limit of quantum field theory" is incorrect and misleading.